# Review count is greater then zero but review list are clear

Tags: bug

From Today marker is showing pending post for review but when I check and clicked on it all review lists are clear. Is this a some type of bug.
[image]

PS: I already checked the question Asked by Adrian in which he face same issue but in my case I am seeing this from morning and still showing count in review. So I don't think its related to any delay also this count change from 5,9,8,5 and so on

Comment: yeah, even I have noticed. As per [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237845/310185). It should be 5 mins difference not more than that. but seems like it is showing the awaiting review for more than 5 mints

Comment: @Ratan yes its still showing in my end with count 13.

Comment: Tushar. even I can see awaiting review count 13

Comment: I have observed this phenomenon as well. It mostly gets blamed on caching, but I believe a more common culprit is when some actions take multiple reviews, you've reviewed them, but they haven't yet cleared. See: [Posts Awaiting Review Broken?](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/posts-awaiting-review-broken)

Comment: @AdrianLarson may be but I never face this before so not quite sure here.